# Entity Framework Migrations in app with outdated version

Tags: c#, vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using the Entity Framework Migrations, at first I am using MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion for whenever I run on clients the same update for last migration .. until it is working very well .. however a scenario has arisen where the client may be with a version on your machine of your outdated app, in that case the app has an error that my template is different from the database .. any solution to this problem?

Comment: The database and the app must be consistent unless the code compares the database version with the app version.  You can't get data out of a database that doesn't exist nor insert data into a database where the column doesn't exist.  So if the database deleted a column a older version of the app will not work on a newer database.  If a column was added in a new version of the database an new version of the software will looking for the added column will not work on an older database that doesn't have the column.

Comment: I understood, my difficulty is how to handle this scenario when the user opens an old version of the application .. I agree with you that it has to be consistent, but this situation can happen and I have to prepare myself in case it comes to occur ...

Comment: That is why the program must check the version of program and version of database to make sure they are compatible.  When they are not then code as to be written to handle the mis-matches in versions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll try this treatment.